# What are those circles and lines I see when I squint at light?

Tags: eye, vision

[image: what I see]

what are those things I see? It happens when I look at a light source (Such as a light bulb) and the circles are supposed to be smaller on the picture. (I recreated what I see)

Comment: If the circles are slowly drifting along, grouped together, they may be "floaters". There's a lot of information online about them. I made this a "comment" instead of an "answer" because I don't know why we get the horizontal and vertical glare. (I get it too!)

Comment: What's the difference between floaters and entopic phenomenon?

Comment: I had to Google entoptic phenomenon. [There's a Wikipedia page about it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_field_entoptic_phenomenon) The page includes a section on floaters.